# Numbers of ways of expressing the sum of a number between [a,b]

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

I need an algorithm to calculate the number of ways of expressing a number N as sum of numbers inside the interval [a, b]

Comment: What for? What have you tried? Is there a target runtime?

Answer (score 4):

What you want is the number of [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_partition) restricted to the interval $[a,b]$. I suggest you take a look at the approaches to count *all* partitions (check references and external links of the article) and adapt it to your needs.